# How much free space do i need to install Fedora 16 using Virtual Box on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10

I have 2.5 GB left on my HDD. Im using WUBI installation. Can I use virtual box to run Fedora in this limited space ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need 6.5 or 7 gigabytes minimum for installing fedora 16